# Как написать команду /stop для бота?

Tags: python, бот

Всем доброго дня! Пишу бота для чата колледжа и тут у меня появилась проблема. Мне нужно, реализовать команду /stop для данного бота, но я не совсем понимаю как это сделать.  Код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'привет', reply_markup=markup1)
markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
itembtna = types.KeyboardButton('Сайт')
itembtnv = types.KeyboardButton('Расписание')
itembtnc = types.KeyboardButton('Информация по всем Учителям')
itembtnd = types.KeyboardButton('Архив учебников')
itembtnh = types.KeyboardButton('Домашние задание на семестр')
markup1.row(itembtna, itembtnv)
markup1.row(itembtnc, itembtnd, itembtnh)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

token = '' #Ваш токен
bot = telebot.Telebot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'привет', reply_markup=markup1)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop']) #В списке вы можете указать любые команды, на эти команды бот будет обращаться к функции stop() - ['start','stop',...]
def stop(message): #Функция которая происходит по команде /stop
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Бот остановлен', reply_markup=markup2)

markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
itembtna = types.KeyboardButton('Сайт')
itembtnv = types.KeyboardButton('Расписание')
itembtnc = types.KeyboardButton('Информация по всем Учителям')
itembtnd = types.KeyboardButton('Архив учебников')
itembtnh = types.KeyboardButton('Домашние задание на семестр')
markup1.row(itembtna, itembtnv)
markup1.row(itembtnc, itembtnd, itembtnh)

markup2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
start = types.ReplyKeyboardButton('/start')
markup2.add(start)
```